# Faster way to loop through dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I'm so desperate to seek help.  I have two dataframes,

**df1 is the patient's hospital admission record.**

| patient_key | admission_dtm | admission_key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | 41765 | P001-001 |
| P001 | 42223 | P001-002 |
| P001 | 42681 | P001-003 |
| P001 | 43139 | P001-004 |
| P001 | 43597 | P001-005 |
| P001 | 44055 | P001-006 |

**df2 is the patient's outpatient appointment record**

| patient_key | appointment_dtm |
| --- | --- |
| P001 | 41645 |
| P001 | 41687 |
| P001 | 41717 |
| P001 | 42162 |
| P001 | 42193 |
| P001 | 42497 |

What I want to do is to find an outpatient appointment before each admission. For example, before P001-001 admission, Patient P001 has 3 times outpatient appointments.

the expected outcome would be like this in df2:

| patient_key | appointment_dtm | admission_key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | 41645 | P001-001 |
| P001 | 41687 | P001-001 |
| P001 | 41717 | P001-001 |
| P001 | 42162 | P001-002 |
| P001 | 42193 | P001-002 |
| P001 | 42497 | P001-003 |

I have used a very silly method like this

```
df2['admission_key'] = ''
for i in df2.index:
    for j in df1.index:
        if df2.['patient_key'].iloc[i] == df1['patient_key'].iloc[i] and 
           df2.['appointment_dtm'].iloc[i] > df1['admission_dtm'].iloc[i] and
           df2.['appointment_dtm'].iloc[i] < df1['admission_dtm'].iloc[i].shift(-1):
           df2['admission_key'] = df1['admission_key']
```

However, since the size is too large and it takes a very long time to run. May I know it there are any smarter ways to do this? Thank you so so much.

Answer (score 5):

This is a perfect use case for [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, 
              by='patient_key', 
              left_on='appointment_dtm',
              right_on='admission_dtm',
              direction='forward').drop(columns='admission_dtm')
```

Result:

| patient_key | appointment_dtm | admission_key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | 41645 | P001-001 |
| P001 | 41687 | P001-001 |
| P001 | 41717 | P001-001 |
| P001 | 42162 | P001-002 |
| P001 | 42193 | P001-002 |
| P001 | 42497 | P001-003 |